# ios: prevent scroll view zoom out of bound

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

in my iphone app if I split the screen to two parts, the top is a scroll view and the bottom is something else, the question is, when the user zoom in the scroll view, how do I prevent it zoom out of bound and hide the second part of the screen? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to set the clipsToBounds property on your UIScrollView to true.